# How can i change the password in neo4j database?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Here i forget my password for the neo4j database how can i change my password.[image]

Comment: Try this http://boopathi.me/blog/reset-neo4j-graph-database-password/

Comment: here ask existing password i forgot that, is there any other option! @FrancescoVicidomini

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The process to reset password depends on your installation:**

1. **Neo4j Desktop:** The process to reset a password for Neo4j desktop is already explained by @loelu, I am just adding a screenshot here: You can set a new password here.
   [image: Neo4j Desktop Password Reset]
2. **Neo4j Server( Zip Installation):** If you are using Neo4j server, You need to find auth file for your neo4j installation and delete it. You can find this file inside "$NEO4J_HOME/data/dbms/" directory.
   You can delete by right click and delete. **Then restart the neo4j.**
   Open a neo4j browser and enter the default username/password:neo4j/neo4j
   Please find the screenshot for password reset of Neo4j server windows (zip installation):

[image: Neo4j server Password reset]

3. **Other Neo4j distributions:** Process is same for other distribution but file location may be different. You can find the location of a **data** folder for your distribution [Here](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/). And then delete **auth** file.

Comment: Thank You i got it  @raj

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're running neo4j Desktop, since you're connected on localhost:7474.
On neo4j Desktop just select the Project you're using and on the Graph tile click on `Manage` (you'll have to stop the graph to do this. On the `Administration` menu you can then set a new password